# Application Insights Telemetry Client - How to show log entries in Azure Application Insights

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I'm using a Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService. In the ExecuteAsync method I start the telemetry operation:

```
using (_telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("someOperationName"))
                { [service implementation goes here] }
```

In the service implementation I use _logger.LogInformation.
And I also call other methods of different classes in my service implementation which also log informations.

These entries are not shown in Azure.

Is there a way to automatically show the log entries of all called methods in Azure Application Insights (Performance -> Operations tab)?

Appsettings:

```
"Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information"
        }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
},
```

ConfigureServices:

```
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
```

The instrumentation key is set in Azure.
I followed these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#net-core-30-worker-service-application

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you use the [ILogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger) interface to log information and you want that to appear in app insights that is doable. On the other hand, if you want to track method calls you will have to do that manually. using  `StartOperation` for example, like you do already.

Comment: The thing is that the Ilogger-logs are NOT shown in application insigths.

Comment: How did you set up the logging, can you share some code? Could also be that the loglevel is not properly set so information messages might not be send to App Insights. Are you using `LogInformation`?

Comment: I've now added the code to my question. Yes, I use "LogInformation"

Comment: @Julida, all the logs are not shown in application insights? or only the logs from the methods from other class are not logged? if it's the 2nd case, can you provide an example of the other methods which are called inside the using statement?

Comment: In the meantime, Azure started to show the logs - I didn't change anything... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Thank you both for helping!

Comment: @Julida, Glad that it's solved. It may due to the delay of the app insights ingestion server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the post for closing this issue:

As per the code / configuration provided by op, both of them are correct. I also confirmed at my side, it works.

So I guess the issue may due to the delay of the application insights ingestion server.